# Is $\mathbb{P}^2$ smooth at every point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the projective variety $\mathbb{P}^2$ smooth at every point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because it is covered by affine opens isomorphic to $\mathbf{A}^2$ and $\mathbf{A}^2$ is smooth (over whatever base field you're using).